# IdentityServer3 and SSO

Tags: authentication, oauth, identity

I have 3 web applications published on 3 separate servers, I have always used Windows Authentication but now some external users should be able to access.

I think [Identity Server 3](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/) could be a good option for a SSO solution, but I don't undestand if user needs to sign in on each application separately.

Here is an example: I have example.com/app1, example.com/app2, otherSite.com/app3, the user sign in using app1, do the user need to sign in also on app2 (same site, different application) and app3 (different site and application)? Is it possible to log on in a single site and not asking again for the credential on the others? Same for the logoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, the SSO using IdentityServer 3 can work this way, and this is a useful resource that carefully explain how to plan for an [extensive SSO](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/introducing-single-sign-on-to-an-existing-asp.net-mvc-application/).

Some details/link/tutorials to a practical implementation are still welcome as an answer to original question :)